# Get count of primefaces datatable checked checkboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am pretty new to primefaces.

Currently im using a datatable that has a multiple select checkbox.

My problem is that I have to check if one of the row is selected or not depending on which i have to enable or disable a button on load using javascript.

Current i have used the following code $("tabs:table").getSelectedRowsCount();

tabs: id of tab
table: id of the datatable

the getSelectedRowsCount function returns null or is not a function error.
I have even tried

$("tabs:table:checks:checked").length;

checks: id of chekcbox

This always returns 0

Would be very helpful if someone can help me out with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$("#tabs [type=checkbox]:checked").length;
```

Note: you said  tabs: id of tab table.